# How to pull locations/data from an embedded Google map on another website?

Tags: google-maps, download, embeddable-web-maps

Is there a way to download the point locations from an embedded Google map? I want to compare the locations of these businesses to a rail network.

[image]

Comment: view-source:https://directory.localfirstaz.com/listing/agriculture-food-production/p:5 [line 5226] lists the coordinates

Comment: what happen when don't exist the button that you say. https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/embedviz?q=select+col3+from+11-YMYbRj5C5_c1Qaj5a1836nUfZvKrHMm-FkxIT4+where+col19+in+(%27Portada%27,+%27Limites%27,+%27Font+visitada%27,+%27Font+desapareguda%27,+%27Pendent+de+visitar%27,+%27Acc%C3%A9s+no+autoritzat%27,+%27No+localitzada%27)&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=39.633802797573956&lng=2.971446096409295&t=1&z=10&l=col3&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=KML example that I say